# Calculate percentage of a circle from center to out on click

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to get the percent radius of an arc (circle).

The idea is, on click event on the canvas, find the element that collide with click point. I did it, there is no problem to find the element that collide.

Bu i want to calculate if an element's type is a circle, calculate the collide percentage from center of the arc to the outside.

[image]

The code below is for collision detection.

```
if(element.type == "circle") { // circle detection
    let dx = x - element.left,
        dy = y - element.top,
        dist =  Math.abs(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));

    if (dist <= element.width / 2) {
        collision = {
            hitTo: // calculate percentage???,
            object: element
        };
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do this. Can you help?

Comment: What is x and y? Is it position of click event?

Comment: Yes. From global offset (canvas)

Comment: Can you explain why you are calculating dist from top-left position? Shouldn't it be from center of circle?

Comment: That function is for finding the element if any collision happens with user click. Nothing related to calculation of percentage from the element center.

Comment: To detect collision you are using `dist <= element.width / 2` i.e. dist < radius.
But you are calculating dist from top-left position of element. This should be from center.

Comment: Silly me... Actually, dx is already given the current position from the center. For example, we have a canvas sized 100x100px, and we have a circle in it sized 40x40 positioned at 50x50. When we click to global offsetx as 50 and offsety 50, we already have the collision and the center of the circle. Change offsetx position to 65, we are now in the circle but not horizontally centered. Away from it's center by 15px. So: `Math.round(Math.abs(dx) * 100 / (element.width / 2))`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have x and y position from the center of the circle (not from the top-left) then you can calculate the percentage by using inverse tangent trigonometric function.

```
var x = 0.5;
var y = 0.5;
var angle = Math.atan(y/x);
var percentage = 100 * angle / (2 * Math.PI);
console.log("Percentage: ", percentage);
```

For example, with both x and y set to 0.5, you get percentage equal to 12.5

Comment: The problem is, we are x and y positions are the global mouse position on the canvas width full height and full width (eg: 1280x720). But the circle width is between 100 and 200. That function above is for just collision detection based on canvas x and y and the position of the arc drawn. Maybe i dont get it, maybe if you do it on an example would be better.

Comment: By the way, element left and element top values are calculated from the center of the arc.